# Generated entities by doctrine for User Interface seems wrong in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doc

I went through the documentation an wanted to add my own User provider (just for understanding the hole thing)
Class just called Account and no User

So i did it like the documentation said:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

After calling 
     `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BaseBundle/Entity/Account` the getter and setter methods was created.

I edited the `security.yml` file and had a look to the interface. 
    FatalErrorException in Account.php line 243:
    Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)´´

```
public function set0($0)
{
    $this->0 = $0;

    return $this;
}
```

Why this is generated by Doctrine?
There was no variable "0"

When I'm deleting the getter and setter for 0 the new error is:
`Property Runalyze\BaseBundle\Entity\Account::$0 does not exist`
I think in this context the 0 comes, when I'm not authenticated?

Just beginning with symfony2 and would like to understand this.
What did I wrong?
Running version of symfony is 2.6

For the last "error" the stack trace
`at ReflectionProperty ->__construct ('Runalyze\BaseBundle\Entity\Account', '0') 
in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php at line 82
at RuntimeReflectionService ->getAccessibleProperty ('Runalyze\BaseBundle\Entity\Account', '0') 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php at line 893 
at ClassMetadataInfo ->wakeupReflection (object(RuntimeReflectionService)) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php at line 537`

Class properties
    // Runalyze/BaseBundle/Entity/Account.php
    namespace Runalyze\BaseBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_account")
 *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Runalyze\BaseBundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;
```

Comment: There must be some sort of typo in your class properties. Can you provide us with your class properties only, no need for the get/set methods.

Comment: Hi, @mipapo. I meant the class properties of **Entity\Account** cause, there is where your error appears to be. Basically, when you execute the command for generating entities, the script looks for your class properties and annotations, and based on that it creates your get/set methods.

Comment: Hi @Andariel , sry this is the right class. Just copied the original file (before generating Entities by Doctrine)  (forgot to change name of class. In the right version it was okay.

Comment: @Andariel I really just used the parts between `class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable` and `}` from the documentation

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same error, but it all went like it was supposed to be. Symfony version is 2.6, all properties generated normally. I still believe it was some sort of typo. Try re-creating your files and generate your methods again. Right now I'm out of ideas, so someone else can come up with better explanation.

Comment: Well it seems a problem with the namespace:
I had this Entity unter namespace Runalyze\Entity\Account
Now i tried AppBundle\Entity\Account.
There were no setter and getter for 0 generated. Seems strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i don't know how that happened, but:
I found a file `Resources/config/doctrine/Account.orm.yml`
I don't know when this was generated, but there was a "0" field. 
I deleted the file and run the generation of the getter and setter again.
This worked fine.

But thanks to @Andariel for trying to find my mistake!

Comment: When you generate entities you can chose to use annotations,yml or xml.  It's not uncommon to accidentally generate yml by mistake.  The yml files get tucked away out of sight and basically override any annotations you try to use without warning.  It's not an uncommon error.